# Domain name for Google reCaptcha v2 issue

Tags: asp.net, recaptcha

I was reading this article on Google reCaptcha v2 from here: `www.codeproject.com/Articles/874150/Google-reCAPTCHA-in-ASP-NET-MVC`

Just noticed that we need to give a domain name to get public and private key at the time of registration but when I am developing a site and running in my pc for testing purpose then my site url look like `localhost:port/pagename.aspx`

Just tell me Google will accept this name `localhost:port/pagename.aspx`?
if no then what would be the best workaround.

If yes then when I will host my site after purchasing a domain then my url may look like `www.mysite.com/mypage.aspx`. So tell me do I need to do again a registration where I may have to put my new domain name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really have a domain name first in order to get the key.

Once you've got this, all the keys work with localhost.

https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/start

Comment: once we enter the domain name and later after few months can we change the domain name ? changing the domain name causes to generate another new pair of public / private keys. let me know. thanks

Comment: Just generate a new key when you have another domain. It's not a big deal to change it in your code.

Comment: Nowadays it's possible to use ip as domain, or just the extension of the domain you are hosting on.